# How to include comments when converting from DOCX to PDF with the help of docx4j?

Tags: java, pdf, docx, docx4j

I am converting DOCX files to PDF. To do this with [docx4j](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j) is simple.

```
Docx4J.toPDF(pack, new FileOutputStream(dir + "out.pdf"))
```

This will result in a PDF file made from the source DOCX file, but it does not include comments from source DOCX file. 
With the help docx4J I can get the comments in the code the following way.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage pack = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(target);
CommentsPart parts = (CommentsPart) pack.getParts().get(new PartName("/word/comments.xml"));
if (parts != null) {
    for (Comment comment : parts.getContents().getComment()) {
                List<Object> actualComment = comment.getContent();

    }
}
Docx4J.toPDF(pack, new FileOutputStream(dir + "out" + i + ".pdf"));
```

"actualComment" list is one instance of a comment, holding in a list each line of a comment. From this list it would be easy to recreate the original comment, but I find no conversion, where I could input this information.

Is there a conversion in docx4j, where it includes the comments from the word file?
Do you have any suggestion on how could I add all comments to the PDF? (open-source solution only please)

I know [documents4J](https://github.com/documents4j/documents4j) can do that, but I am converting DOCM files into DOCX and then into PDF. In my case documents4J does include comments, but leaves out random information, so it is inaccurate or my input is somehow special, but my DOCM to DOCX is 100% correct and docx4j finds every information, even comments, it just does not include it on the final PDF.